# Copy column from one googlesheet to another using API with background colours

Tags: python, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to copy column from one googlesheet to another using API with background colours. I can already get service using this function.

```
def get_service():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', scopes)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    return service
```

so I can now use this function to read the table and get [this response](https://freetexthost.net/nrAAeHw)

```
def get_rows(service, spreadsheet_id, ranges):
    request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, includeGridData=True)
    response = request.execute()
    return response
```

I want to make function copy_column, that copies column from one sheet to another.

```
def copy_column(from_spreadsheet_id, to_spreadsheet_id, from_sheet, to_sheet, from_column, to_column, number_of_cells):
    pass
```

I think I found solution on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615619/copy-background-color-from-one-column-to-another-with-nodejs-google-sheets-api?rq=1), but its written in Node.js, can somebody help me converting to to Python?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. You want to copy the background colors from a column on a Google Spreadsheet to other column on other Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? 2. What is `number_of_cells` of `def copy_column(from_spreadsheet_id, to_spreadsheet_id, from_sheet, to_sheet, from_column, to_column, number_of_cells):`?

Comment: Hi, number_of_cells is how many cells in the column should be copied.

Comment: And I don't want to copy just colors, I want values too.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_service():
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', scopes)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    return service
```

```
def sheet_name_to_sheet_id(service, spreadsheet_id, sheet_name):
    request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id)
    sheets = request.execute()["sheets"]
    for sheet in sheets:
        if sheet["properties"]["title"] == sheet_name:
            sheet_id = sheet["properties"]["sheetId"]
            break
    return sheet_id
```

```
def copy_column(from_spreadsheet_id, to_spreadsheet_id, from_sheet, to_sheet, from_column, to_column):
    service = get_service()
    request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=from_spreadsheet_id, ranges=[from_sheet + "!" + from_column + ":" + from_column], includeGridData=True)
    response = request.execute()["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]

    to_sheet_id = sheet_name_to_sheet_id(service, to_spreadsheet_id, to_sheet)
    to_column_index = ord(to_column) - 65

    body = {
        "requests": {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": to_sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1000,
                    "startColumnIndex": to_column_index,
                    "endColumnIndex": 10
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat, userEnteredValue",
                "rows": response
            }
        }
    }
    request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=to_spreadsheet_id, body=body)
    response = request.execute()
```